# Symfony2 Jquery not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

So I made a simple function with jQuery to check is it working and it isn't. I don't know why this happens since I did everything I found on other stack questions. It just does not do anything...

Everything i have done by now:

1) I created the script and saved it in a file:

```
$('.plus').on('click', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);
    alert("product id "+$this.parent('.item').find('input').data('id') + " Quantity "+$this.parent('.item').find('input').val())
});
```

2) I added the code in twig to make the script work:

```
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" value="2" data-id="1" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus">+</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">-</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" value="2" data-id="2" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus">+</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">-</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" value="2" data-id="3" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus">+</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">-</a>
</div>
```

Now in my base.html.twig I added the jquery library to my assetics :

{% block javascripts %}

```
        {# Le Javascript #}         
            {% javascripts 

                'bundles/mpFrontend/assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' // the jquery library       

                %}    

                <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>       
            {% endjavascripts %}

    {% endblock %}
```

Then In my index html, where I want to make the script work I do:

1) extend the base twig: `{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}`

2) I access the scripts:

```
{% block javascripts %} 
    {{ parent() }}  
    {% javascripts 'js/scripts.js'%}
         <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

4) I do the assetic:dump  :

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

5) I added the bundle in my config.yml since i got the error: `You must add "" to the assetic.bundle config` :

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ MpShopBundle ]
```

This is what ive done, and the code still doesnt work. The dump command didnt give me any errors that means that the routes are correct. However the script doesnt work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your javascript code inside jQuery's `ready` event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.plus').on('click', function (e) {
        $this = $(this);
        alert("product id " + $this.parent('.item').find('input').data('id') + " Quantity " + $this.parent('.item').find('input').val())
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok... By far the dumbest mistake of 2015... Thank you!